# i2c 16 channels relay board works wrongly

Tags: arduino, relay

I have 6 16 Channel realy boards. I use them with Arduino mega.

Some of works fine, some of not! My code is same.

for example

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
Wire.write(0x00); // IODIRA register
Wire.write(0xff);  // set entire PORT A as output
Wire.endTransmission();
```

if i use this code, all relay closes. if i write;

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
Wire.write(0x00); // IODIRA register
Wire.write(0b11111110);  // triggers first relay
Wire.endTransmission();
```

with this code, you trigger relay 1 on port A. if u write 0b11111101 as address you trigger relay 2.

But in one relay board, some off address triggers another relay too. For example if i want to trigger first relay and write address as 0b11111110 it triggers second relay too. (another relay boards it don't happens)

You will probably say, "check wires", yeah i checked million times, all are true. My code is true, because it works well on other relay boards. And this board runs successfully 1 week ago. and now not!

[image: My Relays, There are 6]

What am i asking?

I use different function on this relay board several days ago. board i2c address is still same, port addresses are same, but i am affraid, relay address could be changed because of this code? Is there anyway to reverse default case?

Comment: Which IO expander chip it uses? Are all expanders on same bus? Do they all have different I2C addresses so you can address each board and relay separately?

Comment: i use MCP23017. Yes all relay boards has different i2c address (0x20, ... 0x25) i have 6 relay modules. 3 Relay board works well (0x21, 0x23, 0x25) three is not, when i trigger 1 relay, that triggers another relay too.

Comment: So how is the relay board address configured? Can you show a schematic how the address pins are connected?

Comment: @MuhammedEminoglu - IMHO more clear details are needed, to help readers. I've nearly written an answer a few times, but each time I realised I needed to ask too many clarification questions... You've now added new info in a comment, that **three** of your boards are misbehaving - but in the question you said that on "***one** relay board, some off address triggers another relay too*". This is why the situation is unclear for readers. There are several ways to find the difference(s) between working & non-working boards. History is also important, since you said 1 non-working board used to work.

Comment: i added picture main question. There are 2 relay board each site. Upper relay boards works fine, but others not. Same code, same configuration. I really wonder why.